# woocommerce checkout. creating accounts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

How to turn off creating accounts in woocommerce checkout? After sending the request, a new account is created. How to disable this and to have access to unauthorized users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove this from woocommerce >> settings >> checkout.

Turn on "Enable guest checkout"

Please see attached screenshot.
[image]

Comment: This done. But after submit payment creating a new user.

Comment: In this case, you will have to make custom code to check if user is authorized, if not, then redirect to somewhere else.

Comment: In woocommerce checkout when need entered billing i need entered password and after checkout in table wp_users exist new user [screenshot](http://pasteboard.co/47pxaMtYh.png)

Comment: I don't understand. Can you share screenshot on awesome screenshot?

Comment: You will have to check whether user is logged in or not and if logged in then authenticated or not. If user is not authenticated, then you can redirect him to home page. So, only logged in and authenticated users will access your checkout page and they will never see this password field.

Comment: But i need  to have access for unauthorized users

Comment: If you enable guest checkout, then you can allow access to unauthorized users and their account will also be not created. * You need to enable it.